# annotate in ruby on rails gets command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, annotations, github

I am using the following gem from https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models.
I placed the following code into my gem file and ran bundle install. However when I run annotate, I get a "command not found" Not sure why this is, it should be working I think.

```
gem 'annotate', :git => 'git://github.com/ctran/annotate_models.git'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotate command isn't in your path. The gem may not have been installed environment wide (and was just installed for your app locally by bundler).

Try running `bundle exec annotate`.

If you will be using the gem for more than one project, you could also install it in your environment using `gem install annotate` or install from the github source:

```
git clone git://github.com/ctran/annotate_models.git annotate
cd annotate
rake build
sudo gem install pkg/annotate-*.gem
```